# Ajax displays images from var defined source. How to code button to replace vars for new source?

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables, url

I have used ajax to grab all image urls from a directory and render them as actual images on the screen. In addition, I also grabbed the urls of the full size versions (they have same file name, just different folder) so when you click the thumbnail, the large image displays. This all works fine.

The folder paths are defined by 2 variables.

How would I code a link that onclick, would change the urls and display a whole new set of images.

**These are my 2 variables:**

```
var folder = "gallery1/thumbs/";
var folder2 = "gallery1/fullsize/";
```

**Here is the rest of my ajax:**

```
$.ajax({
    url : folder,
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
            if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) { 
                $("#grid").append( "<a class='item' href='"+ folder2 + val +"'><img class='squares' src='"+ folder + val +"'></a>" );
            } 
        });
    }
});
});
```

The goal is to click a link to change those urls for a new set of images **without reloading the page**.

Any ideas on how this code should look?

Comment: Not quite understand the problem description. What I learn from your code is, after the ajax call complete, it create a new <img> thumbs wrapped with an anchor. When you click the anchor, it shows full size image. Now you don't want to show the full size image, instead, shows next image?

Comment: Hello. No, everything works fine. I just want to add hyperlinks to the webpage that when clicked will load up a new gallery in place of the gallery that is present.  For example, everything that is displaying now is from lets say gallery1.  I want the gallery replaced with gallery2 onclick.  That means the hyperlink would need to update the values of the variables and reload the new gallery images.  but i do not want a page refresh.  just replace the current content with a new gallery.

Comment: Im confused. It is resolved?

Comment: i added comment before I was done typing. sorry. see my comment above

Answer (score 0):

I think the main idea is about how you retrieve the presenting gallery, fire a new ajax to get the new image url (both full image and thumbnail) and update those back to the `<a>` and `<img>` attribute. Demonstrate below. Because i don't know what does "Presenting" gallery define, I just replace the last gallery.

Please ignore the ajax details because there are extra code to deal with the picsum api and not related to your problem. Just focus on the success call back.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#add-image').on('click', function() {
    newImage();
  })

  $('#replace-image').on('click', function() {
    replaceLast();
  })

});


function newImage() {

  var xhr;
  var _orgAjax = $.ajaxSettings.xhr;
  $.ajaxSettings.xhr = function() {
    xhr = _orgAjax();
    return xhr;
  };

  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://picsum.photos/100/100/?random',
    success: function(data, status, hxr) {
      var thumbUrl = xhr.responseURL;
      var fullUrl = thumbUrl.replace('/100/100', '/480/320')

      // create <img> and wrap it with <a> and put it under grid
      $('<img>', {
        class: 'squares',
        src: thumbUrl
      }).wrap($('<a>', {
        class: 'item',
        href: fullUrl
      })).parent().appendTo('#grid');
    }
  })
}



function replaceLast() {
  var xhr;
  var _orgAjax = $.ajaxSettings.xhr;
  $.ajaxSettings.xhr = function() {
    xhr = _orgAjax();
    return xhr;
  };

  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://picsum.photos/100/100/?random',
    success: function(data, status, hxr) {
      var thumbUrl = xhr.responseURL;
      var fullUrl = thumbUrl.replace('/100/100', '/480/320')

      // find the last gallery
      var lastImg = $('#grid a.item:last-child');
      // change its href url
      lastImg.attr('href', fullUrl);
      // change thumbnail src url
      lastImg.children('img.squares').attr('src', thumbUrl);
    }
  })

}
```

```css
#grid {
  margin: 8px;
}

a.item {
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add-image">
add image
</button>

<button id="replace-image">
replace last image
</button>


<div id="grid">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this very educational approach. It is very useful. However, I really do need to simplify things though.

As you can see, my current code, on page load calls up the defined image folders. I just want buttons on the page to change these source folders to different folders.  That is all.  For example,

    `$("button").click(function(){
    change the urls of var's folder & folder2;
    refire ajax without page reload;
    });

    $("button2").click(function(){
    change the urls of var's folder & folder2;
    refire ajax without page reload;
    });`

Comment: Then can't you just name the ajax logic with a function name and on those buttons' click, call that function again. And, why need two buttons to do the same thing?